# Use nestjs to add unique ObjectID to each document that doesn't have one

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nestjs

Just looking for a bit of guidance. I am connected to my local mongoDB instance and I am trying to build a query that will add a unique objectID to every object in an array that doesn't have an _id already. I am trying to do this in nestjs so I can utilize javascript and get a unique ObjectID. Here is what I have so far.

```
    const temp = await this.vehiclesRepository.updateMany(
      {
        $stipulations: [],
      },
      {
        $set: {
          $stipulations: {
            $function: {
              body: "function (ar) {return ar.map(x => { if(x.hasOwnProperty('_id')) return x; else {x['_id']=new ObjectId(); return x;}})}",
              args: ['$stipulations'],
              lang: 'js',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    );
```

```
  public async updateMany(filter: FilterQuery<T>, doc: UpdateQuery<T>) {
    this.model.updateMany(filter, doc, { upsert: true, multi: true });
  }
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this? Based on my research this seems like the proper method to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my question in the MongoDB shell, with no javascript like so

```
db.vehicles.find().forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.stipulations != null) {
        if(doc.stipulations.length > 0) {
            doc.stipulations.forEach(function(stip) {
                if(stip._id == null) {
                    stip._id = new ObjectId();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    db.vehicles.updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: doc});
});
```

For optimization it is possible to filter purely in find(), but for this one time query I am not posting that.

Answer (score 0):

The [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) operator is an aggregation operator. You should use it within an [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/#std-label-aggregation-pipeline-intro). There is also a [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) operator specifically meant for aggregations.

You should combine the `$function` and `$set` (aggregation) operators within an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Looking into this stuff, thanks for answering!